# Grunt & SASS How to?

Tags: sass, gruntjs, zurb-foundation

I am observing the changes in my SCSS files with `grunt watch`. When I upload these files to my server, nothing of the previous changed will be shown:

Observer:

```
Running "watch" task
Waiting...OK
>> File "scss/app.scss" changed.

Running "sass:dist" (sass) task

Done, without errors.
Completed in 0.804s at Wed Mar 11 2015 20:51:46 GMT+0100 (CET) - Waiting...
```

Can anybody guide through the uploading to a remote server? Or can Grunt & SASS only used on `localhost`?

Comment: grunt watch is in your development environment. its not clear from your question whether your local or remote machine is your development environment.

Comment: Sorry! I am developing on my local machine where grunt watch is running. The files should then uploaded to the remote machine where wordpress is installed.

Comment: The task your using won't do that itself... and most people I know don't do the deployment within the same grunt build, they create a directory (maybe "/build"?) and then ssh/FTP/git push/rsync/etc that to their server.

Answer (score 0):

if you have ssh access to the remote machine you can use https://github.com/jedrichards/grunt-rsync

Comment: Dear Matthew, unfortuantely I do not have a ssh access to my server... :-(

Comment: how do you upload the files? sftp?